# For all users, add automapped shared mailboxes as an additional account in same or new profile of Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

For all users in organization, I need to add automapped shared mailboxes as an additional account in same or new profile of Outlook 2010 with offline/sync slider to All or cache all emails.
User mailboxes on Exchange 2010 with full access permission on shared mailboxes 
Shared mailboxes on Exchange 2010
Users using Citrix environment 2016 with roaming profile
Looking for a script or automated way to achieve this.
I have googled it, however no success. Checked OCT/prf which seems to be not working for me as different users have permission on different mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to add different permission for many users to different shared mailbox, OCT/prf could be inconvenient. We can directly set the permission via Exchange powershell. After giving 'Full Access' permission, shared mailbox will auto-map to new and existing profiles for this user

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "ShareMX" -User "Kevin” -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping $true

This thread: [For all users, add automapped shared mailboxes as an additional account in same or new profile](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee61225a-a65d-41cb-aac0-35720e79631f/for-all-users-add-automapped-shared-mailboxes-as-an-additional-account-in-same-or-new-profile-of?forum=outlook)

Comment: Thank you for input Perry. However I do not want to automap as we are using Outlook 2010 and have OST limit for caching. Thats why I need to configure shared mailboxes as additional exchange account in Outlook 2010, so a new OST will be created for shared mailboxes as well.